# Defining FOLDER level variables in Jenkins using a shared \vars library

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

So I'm trying to make define folder level variables by putting them in a groovy file in the `\vars` directory.

Alas, the documentation is so bad, that it's impossible to figure out how to do that...
Assuming we have to globals `G1` and `G2`, is this how we define them in the groovy file?

```
#!Groovy

static string G1 = "G1"
static string G2 = "G2"
```

Assuming the Groovy file is called `XYZ.Groovy`, how do I define it in the folder so its available for the folder's script?

Assuming I get over that, and that that `LIBXYZ` is the name the folder associates with the stuff in the `/vars` directory, is it correct to assume that when I call

```
@Library("LIBXYZ") _
```

it will make `XYZ` available?

In that case, is `XYZ.G1` the way to access the globals?

thanks, a.

Answer (score 3):

I have a working example [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_egg_jenkins_shared_library) as I was recently curious about this. I agree that the documentation is wretched.

The following is similar to the info in `README.md`.

**Prep**: note that *folder* here refers to Jenkins Folders from the CloudBees Folder plugin. It is a way to organize jobs.

**Code Layout**

The first part to note is `src/net/codetojoy/shared/Bar.groovy` :

```
package net.codetojoy.shared

class Bar {
    static def G1 = "G1"
    static def G2 = "G2"

    def id

    def emitLog() { 
        println "TRACER hello from Bar. id: ${id}"
    }
}
```

The second part is `vars/folderFoo.groovy`:

```
def emitLog(message) {
    println "TRACER folderFoo. message: ${message}"
    def bar = new net.codetojoy.shared.Bar(id: 5150)
    bar.emitLog()

    println "TRACER test : " + net.codetojoy.shared.Bar.G1
}
```

**Edit:** To use a static/"global" variable in the `vars` folder, consider the following `vars/Keys.groovy`:

```
class Keys {
    static def MY_GLOBAL_VAR3 = "beethoven"
}
```

The `folderFoo.groovy` script can use `Keys.MY_GLOBAL_VAR3`.

And then usage (in my example: `Basic.Folder.Jenkinsfile`):

```
@Library('folderFoo') _ 

stage "use shared library"
node {
    script {
        folderFoo.emitLog 'pipeline test!'
    }
}
```

**Jenkins Setup: Folder**

- Go to *New Item* and create a new Folder
- configure the folder with a new Pipeline library:

  - *Name* is `folderFoo`
  - *Default version* is `master`
  - **Retrieval Method** is `Modern SCM`
  - **Source Code Management** in my example is [this repo](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_egg_jenkins_shared_library)

**Jenkins Setup: Pipeline Job**

- create a new Pipeline job in the folder created above
- though a bit confusing (and self-referential), I create a pipeline job that uses this same [this repo](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_egg_jenkins_shared_library)
- specify the Jenkinsfile `Basic.Folder.Jenkinsfile`
- the job should run and use the library

Comment: Amir, I have updated the answer and the GitHub repo to use `vars/Keys.groovy` as a class with static variables. The `folderFoo.groovy` script can use the variables. Please examine and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Please vote/accept the answer that best addresses your question.

Comment: Did, I just don't have enough rep to have it displayed (it is recorded tho...)