# How to access Global variable/ functions in vars/*.groovy Jenkins Library without call method?

Tags: jenkins, shared-libraries, jenkins-groovy

Noob in Shared library,
I am puzzled with [Jenkins document](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) section 'Loading Libraries dynamically'.

Followed the [Stackoverflow_answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846844/defining-folder-level-variables-in-jenkins-using-a-shared-vars-library), but I have some different needs, just wanted to call a function from library to pipeline with an argument.

**Note:** Jenkins library configuration is correct and library access is already checked with another example with `call` method

vars/foo.groovy contains function

```
//{Root}/vars/foo.groovy
def Foo_Func(Body){
    Body= Body + "This is a Message from Shared Lib."
    return Body
}
```

`Body` Variable is already defined into main Pipeline `'bar.jenkinsfile'`
My real problem is how to call the function from `foo.groovy` without using call method,
I have tried following -

```
//somefolder_in_scm/bar.jenkinsfile
@Library('jenkins-shared-libs') _
def Body_Main=""
deg SUBJECT="Title 1"
def NativeReceivers = "abc@xyz.com"

pipeline{
    node any
    stage{
        script {
            /*Some script*/
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            script {
                foo.Foo_Func(Body_Main)
                // send email
                emailext attachLog: true,
                    mimeType: 'text/html',
                    subject: SUBJECT,
                    body: Body_Main,
                    to: NativeReceivers
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since I have used `_`, I expect that no import needed.
Error which is occurred after triggering pipeline,

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Class.Foo_Func() is applicable for argument types:
```

In the error, why function `Foo_Func` is treated as a class? It might possible that the argument need to be given in different way.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring a Field ?

@groovy.transform.Field
def myVar = "something"

---

script.myScript.myVar

Assuming your file is myScript.groovy.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing an shared lib too.
I think the problem is in the:

```
def Foo_Func(Body)
```

what works for me is:

```
def Foo_Func(Map Body)
```

so if you try:

```
def Foo_Func(String Body)
```

it should work. I think it can't find the function with the right signature.